# Why does this object return same settings?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a Game class that initializes player objects.  I'm initializing two players `p1` and `p2`. Yet when I console log them, they return the same settings, even though I'm setting `p2`'s color to `#000`.

What's the problem?

I've tried `this.p1.color` and `this.p1['color']`

```
var Game = {
players: 2,
p1: {},
p2: {},
currentPlayer: 1,

initPlayers: function(){
    this.p1 = Player;
    this.p2 = Player;
    this.p1.credits = 500;
    this.p2.credits = 800;
    this.p1['color'] = '#3e3e3e';
    this.p2['color'] = '#000';
    console.log(this.p1);
    console.log(this.p2);
}

}

 var g = Game;
 g.initPlayers();
```

`Console.log` is showing

```
 Object {credits: 800, moves: Array[0], color:'#000', getMoves: function, checkPlayer: function, enterMove: function…}
 Object {credits: 800, moves: Array[0], color:'#000', getMoves: function, checkPlayer: function, enterMove: function…}
```

Even though I'm setting them separately above.

Clearly the setting of the values is working, both with brackets and dot notation, however, it's as if only the final values make it.  And copy to both `p1` and `p2`.

Am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: Btw, `Game` is not a class, but prototype. Until ES6 comes out, JS doesn't have classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript when you assigning something to an object (e.g. `this.p1 = Player`), you don't create new object, but only link to the existing one. You'll need to create a fresh object, using `Player` as prototype:

```
this.p1 = Object.create(Player);
this.p2 = Object.create(Player);
```

Similarly, when you create new game you, better use `Object.create()` if you want to have more than one:

```
var g = Object.create(Game);
```

Comment: Thanks, I now have a problem, where Im storing moves in these objects.  And moves are just x,y coords.  I want each user to have their own moves[] array.  However as I store the moves with this.moves.push, and access each seperate players, moves[] array, they show me both players cumulative moves.??? As if both objkects are accessing the same moves[] array???  Even though theyr initialized empty in the Player object when its created;

Comment: @KyleK this is a new question, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

When you set

```
this.p1 = Player;
this.p2 = Player;
```

You make both variables hold the same object. I'm not sure of what you want so here are two hypothesis :

**1)** If you want to have separate copies of the `Player` object, you should clone them, for example like this (for a non deep cloning) :

```
this.p1 = {};
this.p2 = {};
for (var k in Player) {
   this.p1[k] = Player[k];
   this.p2[k] = Player[k];
}
```

**2)** If `Player` is a class, as the capitalized name would suggest, then what you need is an instanciation, which is done using `new` :

```
this.p1 = new Player();
this.p2 = new Player();
```

Comment: but doesnt invoking Player just instantiate a new Player from my Player Class??

Comment: @KyleK No, to instanciate you need to use the `new` operator.

Comment: ok, if I do that, it says Object is not a function....do I need an init function or what?

Comment: It means Player is not a constructor. Your question was very incomplete... you should have included the relevant code...

Comment: Guy above seemed to help me just fine with what I gave him?? Sorry....Im new to the whole JS object thing

Comment: He could see from the `Object is not a function` error that you didn't use a proper constructor. I'd suggest you to read that : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript